# How to manipulate text pasted into a JTextField, but not typed input?

Tags: java, swing, textfield, jtextfield

My application offers the possibility to copy text from a `JTextArea` to a `JTextField` (used as editor component of a `JComboBox`, but I assume that doesn't matter) and I'd like to provide to remove leading and trailing whitespace if a boolean condition is `true` (e.g. a check box is checked). Entering leading and trailing whitespace into the `JTextField` should still be possible, only the pasted text should be manipulated as described.

I added a `DocumentFilter`, but it responds to both typed changes and pasted changes and I don't find any condition in its method arguments which allow to distinguish typed from pasted insertions. A `KeyListener` doesn't respond to pasted changes.

Comment: So you want to differentiate between paste action and type action in JTextField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't find any condition in its method arguments which allow to distinguish typed from pasted insertions. A KeyListener doesn't respond to pasted changes.

Listener does not provide a direct means to determine whether the input comes from a paste-action. But I have a simple work around solution which may work.

1. Use a `DocumentListener` to detect for text changes in the `JTextField`. If changes were detected, proceed to next step.
2. Grab the String text from the `Clipboard` object.
3. Compare text within the `JTextField` and the text from the `Clipboard`. If the Strings are the same, we assume pasting has occurred.

---

In case the user paste some text in-between existing text in the textfield, you can get the caret position and compare the String from the caret position onwards.

---

**Update:**

To read from Clipboard:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;

Clipboard cb=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
System.out.println(cb.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I added a DocumentFilter, but it responds to both typed changes and pasted changes and I don't find any condition in its method arguments which allow to distinguish typed from pasted insertions

I have never tried it but maybe you can use the `EventQueue` class. Specifically you might be able to use the `getCurrentEvent()` method.

I would guess that if the event type is `keyTyped` then it was generated by typing into the text field.

Other events would be generated if the paste was done using CTRL_V from the keyboard or if you click on a menu item that does the paste.

So I would guess you just need to check if the event is not a "KeyTyped" event and invoke your custom paste logic.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment? At least until it's confirmed, yeah?